# Disable Auto HTML Parsing in Excel 2007

Tags: html, excel

I'm trying to paste some HTML code into Excel. I have a SQL query that generates HTML and inserts image and text at certain points. I then need to paste this into a single field in Excel 2007.

The problem is that Excel automatically parses the HTML and displays a full on web page, complete with styles and pictures. It also tries to spread everything over several rows and columns. This is no good, and I'd like to turn the feature off. I just need it in plain text, no formatting. I've tried paste special, formatting the cells beforehand and searching Excel options, but came up with nothing.

I've searched the net but have found surprisingly little information on the issue. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: When I right-click Paste special... then I can coose to paste the HTML as plain text only and it works for me. (using Excel 2011)

Comment: Hmmm, might be time to upgrade. Paste Special only gives me the options of Unicode Text or Text, both of which do the same thing